# Align text in a QComboBox without making it editable?

Tags: qt

I have a `QComboBox` that looks like:
[image]

Online you see a lot of people posting code to center the label on `QComboBox` that looks like:

```
 auto cmb = new QComboBox(parent);
 cmb->setEditable(true);
 cmb->lineEdit()->setReadOnly(true);
 cmb->lineEdit()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
```

This doesn't work because it changes the behavior of the widget, requiring the user to use tiny navigation buttons at the side of the widget:
[image]

I tried to use a style sheet property but it seems to have no effect

```
{
             cmb->setProperty("text-align", "center");
             cmb->style()->unpolish(cmb);
             cmb->style()->polish(cmb);
             cmb->update();
}
```

Anybody know how to center a `QComboBox` without setting it to editable mode?
C++/Python solutions are fine.

Comment: Did you tried to do it with the Qt stylesheets something like `qApp->setStyleSheet("QComboBox {text-align: center;}")`. Probably it is not a text-align. Also you can check if you need to style QLineEdit inside QCombobox.

Comment: @johngull The QLineEdit object exists only when you set it to "editable" mode. Which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the source code of QComboBox and it is drawn using the complex control mechanism defined by each style. Unfortunately (as of Qt 5.12) the alignment of the text label is hard-coded to left-alignment as seen in the following code:

```
proxy()->drawItemText(p, editRect.adjusted(1, 0, -1, 0), 
                      visualAlignment(cb->direction, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter), 
                      cb->palette, cb->state & State_Enabled, cb->currentText);
```

The only way that I have been able to get the appearance of centered text is by adjusting the padding-left value of the style sheet as so:

```
comboBox->setStyleSheet("QComboBox {"
                        "   padding-left: 20px;"
                        "}"
                        );
```

By doing this and by setting the minimum width of the ComboBox so all items are also centered when the drop down is visible, I am able to achievea centered look. You may have to adjust the padding-left amount to get the appearance you want.

Comment: hey, looking at the latest source in github it seems like that code changed and is no longer hardcoded https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/widgets/styles/qcommonstyle.cpp#L2225
does that mean we can change the alignment now ? (the docs didn't change and don't mention it)

Comment: unfortunately this code is not included yet into the Qt 5.15.1 code.. so hopefully in the next version it's possible

Answer (score 2):

Override the paintEvent, copy the qt source code, except:

```
painter.drawControl(QStyle::CE_ComboBoxLabel, opt);
```

This is to prevent drawing text.

And draw the text:

```
QPainter painter2(this);
QStyleOptionButton buttonOpt;
buttonOpt.initFrom(this);  // init states, such as hover, disable

QRect editRect = this->style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_ComboBox, &opt, QStyle::SC_ComboBoxEditField, this);
buttonOpt.rect = editRect;  // text rect
buttonOpt.text = opt.currentText;
this->style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButtonLabel, &buttonOpt, &painter2, this);  // as button text
```

Now, you can algin text in qss:

```
QComboBox{
    text-align: center;
}
```